# "domain" in resolv.conf shows the wrong domain name

Tags: 12.04, resolv.conf

I have noticed that the "domain" field in `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the domain name of a network I do not use any more. Is there a program/application available that can search for the right domain name and write it to the `resolv.conf` file?

The reason why I would like to have the correct domain name in the "domain" field is that I want to install a program that needs the host name of the computer. During the installation procedure I get the message "could not successfully ping hostname.old-domain-name". Obviously this does not work because I am not connected to that network any more.

I would appreciate very much if someone could help me finding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

A given machine can have multiple domain names, but let's assume that your machine has one (main) [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

It is DNS that determines what your machine's fully qualified domain name is, not the machine itself (... although the machine's fully qualified domain name may be recorded locally in one or more configuration files, e.g., in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.)

Let's say your machine's system hostname is `foo`. Usually the machine is called `foo` in DNS too (although, to repeat, it can have other names as well.) You need to ask DNS what foo's fully qualified domain name is.

Let's say your machine's fully qualified domain name is `foo.bar.com`.

"In the old days" your hosthame would then be `foo` and `/etc/resolv.conf` file would contain `domain bar.com`. (**Warning**: in the old days different distributions handled the domain name differently, e.g., by including it in the system hostname, but most distros don't do that anymore.)

**Nowadays the `search` option replaces the `domain` option in `/etc/resolv.conf`**, so you should have instead `search bar.com`.

Since Ubuntu 12.04, the file `/etc/resolv.conf` is supposed to be managed by the [`resolvconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/resolvconf.8.html) utility. Suppliers of nameserver information (i.e., nameserver addresses and search domain names) pass the info to `resolvconf` which writes an up-to-date `resolv.conf` file at runtime.

You are using resolvconf if the package is installed and `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Let's assume you are in fact using `resolvconf`. If you obtain an IP address for your principal network interface via the DHCP protocol then generally the search domain is also supplied via DHCP. In that case you need to configure the DHCP server to supply `bar.com` as the search domain name. If, on the other hand, your principal network interface is configured statically then you need to enter the search domain name into the network interface configuration utility that you are using (either `ifup` or [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager)). For `ifup` you put the search domain name on a `dns-search` line in `/etc/network/interfaces` and for NetworkManager you put it into the `Additional search domains` field on the IPv4 Settings tab for the relevant NetworkManager connection.